# GetUserDataAsync throws a "Access Denied" error from connector client

Tags: botframework

**Update 1** Entire login controller is in the snippet now.

**Update 2** Its fixed now. The problem is that, I was running the bot using the emulator and connector client doesn't like it. ConnectorClient generates a userid when the bot is hosted and this userid didn't match with the one the emulator was generating. Hence the access was denied. Long story short the bot has to be hosted and should be accessed using one of the valid channels for the connectorClient to accept your requests. Hope it helps someone else.

**Update 3** Fixed a small error in the api routes @Vish

I've been trying to set up an oauth-flow for an app. I've managed to get userInfo from the service but couldn't bind the access token with the userid from the bot.

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("api/login")]
    public RedirectResult Login(string userid)
    {
        return Redirect(String.Format("https://login.windows.net/microsoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&resource={2}&state={3}",
            "MyClientId",  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Constants.apiBasePath + userid + "/authorize"),HttpUtility.UrlEncode('MyService'), userid));
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("api/authorize")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> Authorize(string state, string code)
    {
        string userid = state;
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/microsoft.com/oauth2/authorize/");
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("MyClientId", "MyClientSecret");
        AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(Constants.apiBasePath + userid + "/authorize"), cc);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ar.AccessToken))
        {
            var client = new ConnectorClient(Constants.botId,Constants.botSecret);
            var getData = await client.Bots.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.botId, userid);
            getData.Data = ar.Serialize();

            var foo = await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.botId, userid, getData);

            //return Request.CreateResponse(foo);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri("/loggedin.htm", UriKind.Relative);
            return response;


        }
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

    }
```

In the code snippet above the Authentication result 'ar' is successfully generated with all required data. Now in the following lines, I'm unable to get  the userData object from the GetUserDataAsync function. It always throws the following error.

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Access Denied",
  "exceptionType": "Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException",
  "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorHandling.HandleError[ObjectT]
}
```

Comment: Show us the LoginController code? Make sure that you don't have an Authorize attribute or such things on your login action.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I just updated the question with the entire LoginController. I did get the tokens from the login service. 'ar' is a fully valid data object with the all inforamtion I need. 
I think I'm unable to access the botFramework data using the botConnector.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to follow the ResumptionCookie approach being shown in the [FacebookAuthSample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot). In that sample you will see that the token is being stored in the Dialog and not in the Web API.

Also, you can try instantiating the client in the following way

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
{
     var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();
     client.Messages.SendMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will checkout the Resumption Cookie approach. 
But this method should also work.  The idea is to save the auth details in the botUserData which will persist throughout the session. 
To do that I need the botUserData which I'm unable to get using the GetUserDataAsync method. 
I'm trying to mimic this [here](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/tracking-bot-state/#concurrency). The method name is different and I've no idea why, visual studio suggested the method I used as the GetUserData was not a valid method.

Comment: Using the Resumption Cookie approach you will be able to save the auth details in the bot user data.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
This is fixed now. The problem was I had configured Authentication in Azure Portal as well which is not required in this context. This caused an additional layer of required authentication which blocked users from accessing Bot on channels like Slack, etc. When I removed authentication in Azure portal, bot started working and I'm able to authenticate using Azure AD through the code.

I'm not able to add comment (requires 50 rep), so posting my question here. Will remove in some time.

@ManikantaReddy, I'm following the same sample, but have been facing different issues getting this to work. I keep getting 401 Unauthorized when trying to click the link to get authorized. My MessagesController.cs looks like this:

```
        try
        {
            string d = (string)message.BotUserData;
            AuthenticationResult ar = AuthenticationResult.Deserialize(d);
            AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/");
            ar = DateTimeOffset.Compare(DateTimeOffset.Now, ar.ExpiresOn) < 0 ? ar : await ac.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(ar.RefreshToken, new ClientCredential(Constants.ADClientId, Constants.ADClientSecret));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return message.CreateReplyMessage($"You must authenticate to use bot: https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/{message.From.Id}/login");
        }
```

My loginController looks exactly the same as yours. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yup! I had this problem too. I should have fixed the code here. So basically what happened was your authentication url was not found. Instead of having the userid in the request path, send it as parameter.
Use this in the reply message 
`$"You must authenticate to use bot: https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/api/login?userid={message.From.Id}"`
and then change the url in the api to as 
`api/login` instead of `api/{userid}/login` and 

`api/authorize` in place of `api/{userid}/authorize`

Comment: Oh also since we cannot have the access to userid, we pass it in the authorization url as `state`. Microsoft would then call back at our url with no change in the value of `state`. Hence we can retrieve our userid back and authorize it. Refer to the updated code above for the implementation.

Comment: @ManikantaReddy, Thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: In my case, it was not the Url that caused the issue. I had explicitly configured Authentication in Azure portal which was unnecessary for our code. I'll update my response with this info.